# Email swapping due to account recovery

Tags: discussion, support

I recently switched my email address on all my linked stackexchange IDs (including SO and SO meta) since I was unable to log into my old account.  The "power of cookies" is what allowed me to make this change, from a different machine where I was still logged in.

However, I then realized the "power of cookies" allowed me to recover my original email address, making this operation unnecessary.  I'm wondering if it makes sense to switch my stackexchange accounts back to the original email address, and whether that would cause any issues or if it is a practice that is frowned upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally up to you, but note that you have a third option: Keep them both. As you'll see when you click "my logins" at the top of your user profile, both email addresses currently allow you to log in to the sites, and that's absolutely fine.

Comment: Hmm...the "my logins" appears to be yet another popup that doesn't work for me.  I'll attempt logging in with my original email.

Comment: Interesting...I needed a different browser to log into OpenID due to existing cookies I didn't want to dump, and the "my logins" popup was then visible.  Apparently, it must have somehow "merged" the accounts.  Thank you!